# Finding interaction Hamiltonian for nano particles

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian

I am studying Quantum electrodynamics (QED) and the core part of this theory is the light-matter interaction (quantized light and matter). I referred many papers and books (Molecular quantum electrodynamics, Interaction Hamiltonian of quantum optics etc), and in all the places the interaction Hamiltonian is derived based on the dipole approximation or multipole. However if we are to find the interaction Hamiltonian for more realistic situation like quantumdots/nano wire to light interaction, what should be considered in the first place?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is "more realistic" about a quantum dot than about a single charged particle? The quantum dot is simply a large number of charged particles interacting with each other in the way quantum field theory prescribes. It would be very hard to describe mesoscopic objects that way, but that doesn't mean that a rational, rather than ad-hoc, QFT mean field approach has to exist the way that it is (falsely) prescribed in non-relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: What do you mean by realistic? A (mathematically well-defined) Hamiltonian to describe non-relativistic extended charges coupled with a quantized EM field (in the Coulomb gauge) has been extensively studied, and it is called Pauli-Fierz Hamiltonian. See this [book](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511535178) by Spohn for an extensive presentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. In some QED related publications I saw a quantumdot modeled as a one dipole. And interaction Hamiltonian is calculated using a formula with dipole moment and transverse electric displacement operator. This is how matter-light interaction is taken in all the research done by D. P. Craig, T. Thirunamachandran, Power, D.Andrews. If the quantumdot is modeled with set of discrete energy levels considering conduction band and valence band with dimensions will there be any possibility to find the interaction Hamiltonian in a different way?. Thanks all